# Clean up and prevent excessive data accumulation in an MobileFirst Analytics 8.0 environment

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-analytics

Our analytics data is taking up almost 100% disk space on the file system. How do we remove the old er data, and prevent such situation from occurring again?

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the url, https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/installation-configuration/production/server-configuration/#setting-up-jndi-properties-for-mobilefirst-server-web-applications to setup JNDI properties in Mobilefirst. You need to
set the TTL values base on  you business requirements, and keep the values as short as possible, so that huge data accumulation does not occur again. To clean up the existing data, you can perform the following

1. Setup the Analytics server with JNDI properties set for TTL and other configuration
2. Stop the Analytics Server
3. Delete the /analyticsData directory contents to discard any initial data (this will not affect as there is no data accumulated yet. So that there is no directories within the analyticsData directory) Note:
   /analyticsData is the default location, please refer
   http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/installation-configuration/production/analytics/configuration/ to verify the actual value in your environment.
4. Restart the Analytics server. (Now the index will be created brand new with TTL in effect causing the proper data purging in place)